# How to color keywords with ccze

Tags: logging, terminal

I use [ccze](http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/ccze/) to colorize my log output.

The man page states:

```
-c, --color KEY=COLOR
    the color of the keyword KEY to COLOR,
    like one would do in one of the configuration files.
```

I tried several combinations to highlight the keyword "SELECT" but nothing worked. Can someone tell me how to use this option to colorize a keyword in a specific color?

Answer (score 3):

You can change only colors of keywords listed on this file:

`cat /etc/cczerc`

Example:

`ccze -c date=yellow`

Comment: this is crazy, what about custom log files ?